# Auto-detect and block proxy IP on port number 22 and 21?

Tags: server, iptables, firewall

On Server Ubuntu 16.04

Exact action is something like: if IP from proxy network and trying `ssh` or `ftp` then put it in `iptables` reject list for 3 days.

Something like fail2ban.

Comment: You want to drop *all* from a host **if** that host tries to use ssh or ftp? Or you want to drop ssh and ftp?

Comment: i want to drop host only if via proxy or vpn. i found some website detects proxy and vpn. i just want the same logic for iptables.

Comment: How do you plan to detect that? If it's over VPN, it's encrypted, so you have **no way** of knowing what services the user attempts to connect to, unless you do SSL MITM, in which case most VPN's should fail. And you'd need a MiTM that supports all the different VPNs out there. As for proxies, you'd need to do deep packet inspection, and look for `CONNECT`s to port 22 or 21. This sounds deeply unpractical. In addition, you can use ssh to tunnel traffic, effectively making it a VPN...

Comment: agree, inspiration came from this website. https://www.iplocation.net/proxy-check . i wonder any tool ever made in linux for this.

Comment: There's many tools that can help you achieve this. But it's not straight forward. It would likely include some sort of HTTP proxy to do HTTP inspection, and some packet sniffer such as snort to inspect general traffic, and some customization of rules.